# How to make a Twig date translatable

Tags: symfony, twig

I am displaying a DateTime object in twig like this:

```
<td>{{ transaction.getDate|date("F - d - Y") }}</td>
```

Now I want the month to be translatable, 
For example `April - 20 - 2012` should be displayed as: `Avril - 20 - 2012`

**Can I do this?
If so, how?**

I am working on Symfony2.

Comment: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/378 Any good?

Comment: Yes thats useful! Thanks. This problem was solved quite some time back though.

Answer (score 13):

or use the [The Intl Extension](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html) :

```
{{ "now"|localizeddate('none', 'none', app.request.locale, "Europe/Paris", "cccc d MMMM Y") }}
```

Will give you something like :

```
jeudi 25 février 2016
```

To enable with symfony 2, add to composer :

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

And activate filters with service :

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Indeed the best answer so far.

Comment: in my case {{ "now"|localizeddate('long','none') }} works like a charm by my wish output '3 de mayo de 1980'

Comment: Month name is not capitalized, how we are supposed to do to uppercase the first character of the month name?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the month part and then translate it:

```
  {% set month      = transaction.getDate|date('F') %}
  {% set dayAndYear = transaction.getDate|date('d - Y') %}

  {{ '%s - %s'|format(month|trans, dayAndYear) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

A another solution with an inline twig solution, and a more readable translation messages file :

```
<td>{{ ('month.'~transaction.getDate|date("m"))|trans|raw~' - '~transaction.getDate|date("d - Y") }}</td>
```

And in your translation file (depends on the configuration you set), for example in messages.fr.yml for a french translation you have to put these lines :

```
# messages.fr.yml
month.01: Janvier
month.02: Février
month.03: Mars
month.04: Avril
month.05: Mai
month.06: Juin
month.07: Juillet
month.08: Août
month.09: Septembre
month.10: Octobre
month.11: Novembre
month.12: Décembre
```

Explanation :

use of ~ operator to convert all operands into strings and concatenates them
use of | operator to apply a filter
use of trans function to translate
use of raw to indicate the date is safe (no need to escape html, js...)

Careful with parentheses because of the operators priority define in
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

The operator precedence is as follows, with the lowest-precedence operators listed first: b-and, b-xor, b-or, or, and, ==, !=, <, >, >=, <=, in, matches, starts with, ends with, .., +, -, ~, *, /, //, %, is, **, |, [], and .:

Explanation of the parentheses in the first part :
('month.'~transaction.getDate|date("m"))|trans|raw

transaction.getDate|date("m") is executed first because | operator has a higher priority on ~ operator.
If month of transaction.getDate is may, then transaction.getDate|date("m") return 03 string
And after 'month.' is concatenate to this string, and then we have month.03

And because we set 'month.'~transaction.getDate|date("m") between parentheses, the filter trans is applied only after the string month.03 was evaluated...