# How would I translate the day return value of date in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this:

```
<li>{{ datum|date('l') }}</li>
```

Which returns:

```
Wednesday
```

But I want it to be translated i.e to dutch or the language of the user how would I achieve this?

I have tried these options:

```
<li>{{ afspraak.datum|date('l')|trans }}</li>
-
<li>{{ afspraak.datum|date('l')|trans|raw }}</li>
```

But it didn't seem to do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Twig date translatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223614/how-to-make-a-twig-date-translatable)

Comment: @AlisterBulman `twig/extensions` is only compatible with twig 2

Comment: Try with "localizeddate"  https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html

Comment: @hous It's only compatible with twig 2 can't require it.

Comment: what error appears when you try to require it ?